# Docker container on Fedora 28 KDE have no internet connection

Tags: linux, docker, networking

since a couple of weeks I'm trying to fix an issue on my new laptop with fedora 28 KDE desktop!

I have two issues :

1. The container can't connect to the internet
2. The container doesn't see my hosts in /etc/hosts

I tried many solutions, disable firewalld, flusing iptables, accepting all connections in ip tables, enabling firewalld and changing network zones to "trusted"! also disbaled iptables using daemon.json! it still not working!!

please anyone can help, it's becoming a nightmare for me!

**UPDATE #1:**

even when I try to build an image it can't access the internet for some reason!, it seems the problem in the level of docker not only containers!
I tried to disable the firewall or changing zones, I also set all connections to "trusted" zone

anyone can help?

**UPDATE #2:**

When I turn on firewalld service and set wifi connection zone to 'external' now container/docker is able to access internet, but services can't access each other

**Here is my yml file :**

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      nabed: {}
    volumes:
    - "../nginx/etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
    - "../nginx/etc/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl"

  api:
    image: nabed_backend:dev
    hostname: api
    command: api
    extra_hosts:
    - "nabed.local:172.17.0.1"
    - "cms.nabed.local:172.17.0.1"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    env_file: .api.env
    networks:
      nabed: {}

  cms:
    image: nabedd/cms:master
    hostname: cms
    extra_hosts:
    - "nabed.local:172.17.0.1"
    - "api.nabed.local:172.17.0.1"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    env_file: .cms.env
    volumes:
    - "../admin-panel:/admin-panel"
    networks:
      nabed: {}

networks:
  nabed:
    driver: overlay
```

inside API container:

```
$ curl cms.nabed.local
curl: (7) Failed to connect to cms.nabed.local port 80: Connection timed out
```

inside CMS container:

```
$ curl api.nabed.local
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.nabed.local port 80: Connection timed out
```

**UPDATE #3:**

I'm able to fix the issue by putting my hosts in my YAML file in **extra_hosts** options
then turning my all networks to '**trusted**' mode
then restarting **docker** and **Networkmanager**

**Note:** for ppl who voted to close this question, please try help instead

Answer (score 2):

Try very dirty solution - start your container in host network - docker run argument `--net=host`.

I guess, there will be also better solution, but you didn't provide details how are you starting your containers and which network is available for your containers.